# Anydesk slows down after some time

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, anydesk

I have an unattended remote machine that runs Ubuntu 22.04.
My local machine runs Ubuntu 23.04.
Both runs Anydesk 6.2.1.

On the remote machine no applications run but Anydesk service.
If I connect to the remote machine just after it started I have a very good response time. Instead, if I connect after - say - a couple of hours it takes seconds to refresh the screen.

Here what I did to find out the reason of the issue:

- check the network speed (speedtest.net) of local and remote machines, before and during the issue. No problems at all: about 60M/15M at any moment.
- check the CPU/RAM load on both machines: again nothing wrong. On the remote machine the CPU was about 4-5% and RAM 30%:

```
    $ free -h
                   total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:           7.6Gi       1.6Gi       3.9Gi       352Mi       2.0Gi       5.3Gi
    Swap:          4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

- tried to restart the Anydesk service, but it didn't fix
- it is enough to logout/login to recovery the responsiveness, but after few minutes again it slows down too much

I'm asking this question here since this issue raised few weeks ago, I guess after an Ubuntu update (but I cannot be sure). Before it always worked fine.

Is there anything I can check or try to find out the cause?